# Samsung monitor which was advertised to support 4K and 240Hz does not do both at the same time

Tags: linux, debian, nvidia, display, resolution

I recently purchased a [Samsung 32" Odyssey Neo G8 4K UHD 240Hz monitor](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/gaming/32-odyssey-neo-g8-4k-uhd-240hz-1ms-curved-gaming-monitor-ls32bg852nnxgo/) to replace an old one. After explicitly setting the refresh rate to 240Hz on the monitor, I connected it to my Linux desktop via DP cable. When I opened display settings it was set to 3840 x 2160 resolution and 60.00Hz. When I clicked on the Refresh Rate setting 240Hz was not there. The maximum available was 120.00Hz. To investigate further I used the `xrandr` command to fetch every single display option.

```bash
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 700mm x 400mm
   3840x2160     60.00 + 120.00*  119.88    59.94    29.97  
   2560x1440    239.97   120.00    59.95  
   1920x1080    239.93   120.00   119.88    60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94
```

As you can see ~240Hz option exists for 1440p and 1080p but not 4K. My GPU is Nvidia and the driver comes from Debian 11 package `nvidia-drivers`, version 470.182.03.

Was this monitor never supposed to support 4K 240Hz? Did I misread the adverts? Or is my display driver outdated? I am aware that Debian 12 has a newer version, 525.105.17. Will updating drivers enable 4K 240hz? If so, is it safe to apt-pin `nvidia-drivers` and upgrade it to bookworm version? I am afraid an error might render the system unusable because it's the display driver.

Side questions:

1. Why does the system prioritize 60Hz over 120Hz in 4K? It keeps defaulting to 4K 60Hz whenever I switch to my new 4K monitor. Can I adjust settings so that it defaults to 4K 120Hz instead?
2. Why does 1440p and 1080p provide 239.9xHz and not 240.00Hz?

Comment: You can only push a certain amount of data down a connection. I don't know your monitor, so it might be that 240 frames per second * 3840 * 2160 pixels per frame is too much. You need a DP2.0 port and cable, DP1.4 **only** allows 48Gb/s. You also want to look at DSC (Display Screen Compression).

Comment: As @icarus says, refresh rate depends on a) the monitor, b) the video card, and c) the cable.  To get 4K @ 240 Hz, **all three** need to support that.  Otherwise, you'll just get the best that all three are capable of.   Look up the specs for your GPU - does it have a DP 2.0 port (or, at least, 1.4 with DSC)?  Is your cable good enough for 4K@240?   Also worth noting: the higher the resolution * frequency, the better the cable (e.g. wire gauge & quality, shielding) you will need....and often the cable provided with a monitor is the cheapest & lowest quality they can plausibly get away with.

Answer (score 0):

The newest NVIDIA driver `535.x` adds support for DSC (Display Stream Compression). See [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/open-gpu-kernel-modules/discussions/238) the full issue and discussion.

Upgrading to `nvidia-driver-535` or later should solve the issue.

[image]

That being said, I think there are still issues to be resolved as there is some kind of pixel row artifacts visible when on high resolutions at 240Hz.

| Frequency | Sample | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120Hz | [image: 120Hz normal pixel distribution] | Normal pixel blending |
| 240Hz | [image: 240Hz pixel row artifacts] | Note how every second row is brighter. |

I think it's some kind of compression artifact or a bug that is quite annoying to look at. I think 120Hz is still the most stable setting.